# Update de un archivo pdf con Angular y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, angular

Quiero hacer un update de un archivo pdf con Angular y laravel, no me deja subir el pdf, pense que del lado del cliente no se manda el archivo pero revise y si se manda, lo que no puede procesarlo es el servidor por lo que entendi, nose si estoy en lo correcto, mi html lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

````
                <!-- Otros campos del formulario -->
                <input type="file" (change)="manejarArchivoInput2($event)" id="inputArchivo2">
                <button id="editar" (click)="editarArchivo()" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Subir Archivo Editado</button>
              </form>``` 
y mi código para validar el archivo y hacer el update lo tengo así: ```manejarArchivoInput2(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.archivoParaEditar = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(this.archivoParaEditar);
    } else {
      console.log('No se seleccionó ningún archivo.');
    }
  }
  subirCompro(idCotizacion:string){
    this.idCotizacion=idCotizacion;
  }
  editarArchivo(){
    if (this.archivoParaEditar && this.idCotizacion) {
      console.log(this.idCotizacion);
      this.comprobanteServi.editarArchivo(this.archivoParaEditar, this.idCotizacion).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log('Archivo editado con éxito', res);
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Error al editar el archivo', error);
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.error('No se seleccionó ningún archivo para editar o falta el idCotizacion.');
    }
  }```
````